# Excel function to mimic RMS calculation returns error

Tags: excel, vba, user-defined-functions

All, below is an Excel VBA script I wrote to try to calculate RMS in Excel.  the `avg` variable is a single cells value, `setter` is a range.  This should sort of mimic a root-mean-square error function.  It needs to be applied on a rolling basis throughout the sheet, not just over one static dataset, thus is it needs to be a UDF.

To be clear, this returns a `#NAME?` error. The formula is entered `=runs_test(S86,T66:T86)`; all of the S and T column are formulas that return numbers.

Any advice is appreciated, thanks!

```
Function runs_test(avg As Double, setter As Range)
Option explicit

Dim i As Variant
Dim counter As Double
Dim er As Double


For Each i In setter

    er = (avg - i.Value) ^ 2
    counter = counter + er

Next i


total = setter.Cells.Count

er = counter / total
er = er ^ (1 / 2)

runs = er

End Function
```

Comment: Start with changing `runs = er` to `runs_test = er` and turn on [Option Explicit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xyVrl.gif).

Comment: `Dim i as Range`. Also, what is `z` for?

Comment: @Jeeped, thanks, and changed/edited - still not working.

Comment: @urdearboy, apologies, that shouldn't be in there.  changed that too.

Comment: We don’t know what “still not working” means. Elaborate. Error? Wrong output? Etc.

Comment: [Option Explicit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xyVrl.gif) should be outside the function at the top of the code sheet in the Declarations area. Click the link for a quick demo.

Comment: Apologies, still getting #NAME? error after the changes.  @Jeeped  I moved the option explicit to outside of the function and still got the #NAME? error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of minor typos fixes and syntax correction produces the following working function.

```
Option Explicit

Function runs_test(avg As Double, setter As Range)

    Dim i As Range
    Dim counter As Double, er As Double
    Dim total As Long


    For Each i In setter

        er = (avg - i.Value) ^ 2
        counter = counter + er

    Next i


    total = setter.Cells.Count

    er = counter / total
    er = er ^ (1 / 2)

    runs_test = er

End Function
```

Note that the function code goes into a public module code sheet, not a private worksheet code sheet. Use Insert, Module in the VBE to bring a public module code sheet into your project.

[image]

Comment: this is very strange - your function worked with the data example you provided.  in my sheet, however, it doesn't work.  is there a reason that it might not work on cells containing formulas, instead of hardcodes?  Thanks again for your help!

Comment: perhaps your formulas are returning text or even text-that-look-like-numbers. hard to state anything definitive without seeing the formula(s). perhaps that is a new question now that the udf appears to work with true numbers.